# Italian Exhibition - A Zebra Puzzle (Einstein's Riddle) Variation

Tags: logical-deduction, logic-grid

You can play this Zebra Puzzle here: https://www.brainzilla.com/logic/zebra/italian-exhibition/

|  | Woman #1 | Woman #2 | Woman #3 | Woman #4 | Woman #5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| shirt |  |  |  |  |  |
| name |  |  |  |  |  |
| surname |  |  |  |  |  |
| painter |  |  |  |  |  |
| time |  |  |  |  |  |
| age |  |  |  |  |  |

Five women are side by side talking about an Italian paintings exhibition. Each woman arrived at the exhibition at a specific time and went to see her favorite painter. Find out who likes Leonardo da Vinci's paintings.

- Shirt: Blue, Green, Purple, Red, Yellow
- Name: Debra, Irene, Judy, Ruth, Teresa
- Surname: Bennett, Gonzales, Hall, Murphy, Perez
- Painter: Caravaggio, Leonardo da Vinci, Michelangelo, Raphael, Sandro Botticelli
- Time: 2:00 PM, 2:30 PM, 3:00 PM, 3:30 PM, 4:00 PM
- Age: 20 years, 24 years, 31 years, 40 years, 52 years

Clues:

1. Irene is at one of the ends.
2. The woman wearing the Yellow shirt is somewhere between the woman who likes Raphael and the 40 years woman, in that order.
3. Mrs. Hall is next to the woman that went to the exhibition to see the Botticelli's paintings.
4. Mrs. Bennett is somewhere to the right of the woman wearing the Yellow shirt.
5. Teresa was the first to arrive at the exhibition.
6. The 40-year-old woman is exactly to the left of the woman wearing the Red shirt.
7. At one of the ends is the woman that arrived at 2:30 PM.
8. Irene is next to Mrs. Murphy.
9. The 31-year-old woman went to the exhibition to see the paintings from Caravaggio.
10. Debra is exactly to the right of the woman who arrived at 3:00 PM.
11. The woman wearing the Purple shirt is somewhere to the left of the woman that likes Da Vinci.
12. The woman wearing the Yellow shirt is somewhere between Mrs. Perez and the youngest woman, in that order.
13. At the third position is the woman that was interested in the Botticelli's paintings.
14. Mrs. Gonzales is at one of the ends.
15. The 24-year-old woman arrived at the exhibition at 3:00 PM.
16. Ruth is somewhere between Mrs. Perez and Mrs. Hall, in that order.
17. The woman who likes Raphael is wearing the Green shirt.
18. At one of the ends is the 20 years woman.
19. The last one to arrive at the exhibition is exactly to the right of the woman who was eager to see the Caravaggio's paintings.
20. Mrs. Hall is wearing the Purple shirt.
21. The oldest woman is exactly to the right of the woman wearing the Yellow shirt.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

> ```
>  |   Trait    | Woman #1 | Woman #2 | Woman #3 | Woman #4   | Woman #5 |
>  |------------|----------|----------|----------|------------|----------|
>  | Shirt      |  Green   |  Yellow  |   Blue   |  Purple    |    Red   |
>  | Name       |  Irene   |  Debra   |   Ruth   |  Teresa    |   Judy   |
>  | Surname    |  Perez   |  Murphy  |  Bennett |   Hall     | Gonzales |
>  | Painter    |  Raphael |Caravaggio|Botticelli|Michelangelo| DaVinci  |
>  | Time       |   3:00   |   3.30   |   4:00   |   2:00     |   2.30   |
>  | Age        |    24    |    31    |    52    |    40      |    20    |
> ```

Answer (score 0):

> According to 1., Irene is at one of the ends so she can't be #2, #3 or #4. 
>  Based on 1. and 2., Irene doesn't wear yellow either. The woman in yellow is #2, #3 or #4. The woman who likes Raphael can't be #4 or #5, and the 40 yo woman can't be #1 or #2. The woman who likes Raphael isn't 40. 
>  Clues 5., 9., 13., 15., 17. and 20. give precise information. We can infer from them that Teresa isn't 24. The one interested in Caravaggio didn't arrive at 3:00 PM. Mrs. Hall isn't interested in Raphael. 
>  Based on 3. and 13., Mrs. Hall must have been #2 or #4. Given 1., she's not Irene. 
>  Based on 2., 12. and 21., the woman in yellow is on the left side of the 40, 20 and 52 yo women. She's not #1, so she must be #2. The oldest woman is #3 and is interested in Botticelli considering 13. The woman who likes Raphael is #1 and Mrs. Perez. She's either 24 or 31 years old, just like the one in yellow. Given 20., Mrs. Hall must be #4. She (the one in purple) is not interested in Botticelli. She's 20 or 40 years old, just like #5. Adding 6. into the mix, we can deduce that the 40 yo woman is #4, therefore Mrs. Hall and wears purple. The 20 yo woman wears red and is #5. The Botticelli fan wears blue. Given 11., only the woman in red can be the Da Vinci fan.
>  According to 1. and 8., Mrs. Murphy is #2 or #4, so since Mrs. Hall is #4, Mrs. Murphy is #2, and wears yellow. Irene is the Raphael fan. Given 9., the 31-year old in question can only be Mrs. Murphy, making Irene the 24 yo. According to 14., Mrs. Gonzales is the Da Vinci fan. Then Mrs. Hall is the Michelangelo fan, and Mrs. Bennett is into Botticelli. 
>  Based on 16., Ruth can be #2 or #3. Given 19., #3 must have arrived at 4:00 PM. According to 10. and 15., Debra can be #2 or #3. Irene arrived at 3:00 PM, so Debra is #2 and Ruth is #3. Judy and Teresa (in no particular order now) share the last two places. According to 7., the 2:30 PM arrival is #5, so she can't be Teresa given 5..

Answer:

> Irene Perez: Raphael, Green, 24, 3:00 PM 
>  Debra Murphy: Caravaggio, Yellow, 31, 3:30 PM 
>  Ruth Bennett: Botticelli, Blue, 52, 4:00 PM 
>  Teresa Hall: Michelangelo, Purple, 40, 2:00 PM 
>  Judy Gonzales: Da Vinci, Red, 20, 2:30 PM

---

<sub>Answer in grid format:</sub>

> ```
> |   Trait    | Woman #1 | Woman #2 | Woman #3 | Woman #4   | Woman #5 |
> |------------|----------|----------|----------|------------|----------|
> | Shirt      |  Green   |  Yellow  |   Blue   |  Purple    |    Red   |
> | Name       |  Irene   |  Debra   |   Ruth   |  Teresa    |   Judy   |
> | Surname    |  Perez   |  Murphy  |  Bennett |   Hall     | Gonzales |
> | Painter    |  Raphael |Caravaggio|Botticelli|Michelangelo| DaVinci  |
> | Time       |   3:00   |   3.30   |   4:00   |   2:00     |   2.30   |
> | Age        |    24    |    31    |    52    |    40      |    20    |
> ```